# LIMIT View All Data from Database in Page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently making a student's directory using PHP and MYSQL.
However I can't control how many students would register and join the site so I'm having a bit of problem in producing the *all_students.php* page.

The *all_students.php* page would get **all users** from the table called `students_users` in my database. So normally:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students_users";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    $age = $data['age'];
...
    echo $name;
    echo $age;
...
```

It's currently working however I noticed that the more users I got, the page becomes as longer and becoming a burden for the users because they have to scroll down for example to names that starts with letter "T".

Any ideas how can I divide the users to display to a single page (like the search results on Google where it displays about 10 results and then it has this `Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 |...`?

I already tried this: 
`"SELECT * FROM students_users Limit 20";` 
and 
`"SELECT * FROM students_users LIMIT 20,20";` for the next page and so on

My only problem is that, I don't know how exactly is my number of users will grow and that for example if I have say: 400 users and I want to divide the `all_students.php` in to viewing theses users using like 10 Pages - `Limit 20` will not be enough. I have to use `Limit 50` or something right?

How can I make it **automatically divides** **all my users** in to displaying within the **10 Pages** view? 
Example: 
10 users - 1 user per page 
100 users - 10 users per page 
500 users - 50 users per page
etc.

without having to constantly change the `Limit` code as my number of users grow?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm this will help you

Comment: @TajKhan Thank you so much! I think this is really helpful!

Comment: @Dranreb - be careful , you **NEVER** can use a LIMIT for pagination without a ORDER clause. LIMIT without an order gives you only a pice of date and it is possible the some records are the same

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take the total users count and based on that you can calculate the records per page.

Answer (score 0):

Do the tricks to generate `limit` dynamically . Divide user_count by 10 as you want to ten view page

```
$sql = " SELECT count(name) as user_count FROM students_users "; 
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$number_of_user = $result['user_count'];
$limit = $number_of_user/10;   // Divide user_count by 10 as you want to ten view page 
$limit = round($limit, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```